# Origins of possessive pronouns

Tags: pronouns, possessives, apostrophe

If *apostrophe + s* is the acceptable way of denoting a genitive in English, is it possible that possessive pronouns, such as *hers*, *ours* and *yours*, started life as possessive adjectives with *apostrophe + s*?

E.g. *her's*, *our's*, *your's*, *their's*? Perhaps, even *his'* ?
*Its* and *my* obviously stick out from this tempting pattern.

Is there any evidence that this might be the case, or is the *'s* completely unrelated?

Comment: Sorry, about the *'s* — was slightly confused by that. Will comment before editing next time :)

Comment: @jimi - no problem. Thanks for neatening it up - much easier to read now, and I see how the formatting works :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The possessive *'s* comes from the masculine [genitive case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case) ending on *-es* in [Old English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_pronouns). This means that you could say "of [the] man" by simply sticking *-es* after "man". The genitive case was often used to indicate the possessor of something. In German, the genitive case is still used, and it ends on *-(e)s* for masculine and neuter singular words: *the man = der Mann; the man's house = des Mannes Haus.* As you see, the genitive is also used with articles.

The *s* in which most possessive pronouns end comes from the same genitive ending, either directly or indirectly by analogy. The genitives *his, whos* and *yours* (plural) already existed in Middle English.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_pronouns) It is conceivable that modern *hers*, for example, which was something like *her* in Middle English, was formed by analogy with the possessive pronoun *his*, or by simply attaching the possessive *s* to it, if that already functioned as a productive suffix. Note that the apostrophe is of later date than the possessive *s*: the possessive of *summer* was simply *summers* in the time of Shakespeare.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_genitive)

Comment: very interesting - so is the apostrophe there for the lost *e* from *-es*?

Comment: @gpr: Sort of. But in fact the -e- was not always there; indeed the -s. wasn't always there either: different classes of words had different sets of endings in Old English, just as in other languages like Latin and German. The "-s"/"-es" spread by analogy in Middle English to all nouns, singular and plural. The apostrophe *may* have been used to represent the '-e-' (which, remember, we still pronounce in some cases, eg "Max's"), but I think it is more likely that it was introduced as an arbitrary graphical device to distinguish possessives. Certainly the rule for plurals is arbitrary.

Comment: (Ran out of characters in the previous comment) I mean that the *s'* as opposed to *'s* has no basis in history or phonetics, and seems to have been adopted quite arbitrarily.