# Why is an apostrophe used in the genitive “-’s”?

Tags: etymology, possessives, apostrophe, contractions

The English possessive isn’t a contraction, but rather a relic of the grammatical case system, so why is an apostrophe used in (most) forms of the possessive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How did an apostrophe plus the letter “s” come to indicate possession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/), [Where did the practice of using apostrophes for possessive nouns but not pronouns originate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95853/), [Origins of possessive pronouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the practice of using apostrophes for possessive nouns but not pronouns originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95853/where-did-the-practice-of-using-apostrophes-for-possessive-nouns-but-not-pronoun)

Answer (score 7):

The apostrophe came into English in the middle of the sixteenth century as a printer’s mark to indicate missing letters. Its use to indicate possession may in part have arisen from the fact that some, but by no means all, Old English nouns formed their genitive with the ending *-es*. The genitive of *scip* (‘ship’), for example, was *scipes* (‘of a ship’), and the apostrophe would have allowed printers to show *shipes* as *ship’s*. (By contrast, the genitive of *nama* ('name') was *naman*).

It’s probably more helpful to see the development of the apostrophe to indicate possession more generally as an arbitrary convention. That is certainly the case with the use of the terminal apostrophe, as in *ships’*, which was not established until the eighteenth century.

Comment: The genitive relative and possessive interrogative pronoun *whose* is a slightly interesting case, so to speak. :)

Comment: Is who/whom/whose the best remaining example of declension in Modern English? The relationship with Latin qui/quem/cuius is striking.

Comment: @DavidGarner: Not such a good example; _whom_ is moribund, more honored in the breach than the observance, while _whose_ is no longer only human in reference like _who_ and _whom_, but is extended to neuter and metaphoric possessives as well. There aren't many good paradigms left in English, though [we used to have some cool ones](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf).

Comment: I hesitated to contradict John Lawler for *whom* I have great respect, but when I showed the previous clause to colleagues [London, UK, tech people] they agreed with me that it was normal, slightly-formal English that wouldn't look out of place in a work doc.  So, moribund maybe, but not dead yet.  As for 'whose', well, I was just drawing a parallel between English and Latin cases, because as an amateur I'm still  amazed that these correspondences persist over millennia.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) the apostrophe is used to mark the loss of the letter *e* that existed in old English to mark the genitive inflection.

Edit:
Here's an interesting post on this subject: [*The Possessive Apostrophe His Origin*.](http://wmjasco.blogspot.fr/2011/08/possessive-apostrophe-his-origin.html)