# Why is "whomse" not a word?

Tags: american-english, british-english, grammatical-case, whom, possessive-pronouns

I often hear people say something like

> For whose benefit is that?

Should it not be

> For *whomse* benefit is that

Who -> Whom
Whose -> Whomse

I know "whomse" is not a real word. My question is: why doesn't it exist?

Comment: Related: [Accidental gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap).

Comment: Interesting question. This actually belongs to a principle in Indo-European languages with respect to the form of genitives; it should be allowed to ask such a question.

Comment: The way things are going, in a few years we might expect 'Why is “whom” not a word?'

Comment: Irish language-blogger Stan Carey postulates [**Whom’s Law:** The more strict or anxious someone is about using ‘whom’ correctly even in informal English, the more likely they are to use it hypercorrectly.](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/whoms-law-of-hypercorrection/)

Comment: @tchrist Surely you mean _Whomse’s Law_?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The easiest way to think about this is to compare to *he him his*:

> **Who** gets the benefit? **He** gets the benefit.
>
> To **whom** does the benefit accrue? The benefit accrues to **him**.
>
> For **whose** benefit is that? That is for **his** benefit.
>
> For **whomse** benefit is that? That is for **hims** benefit.

Obviously that last is unnecessary/wrong—in place of *hims* (or him's) we have *his*, and in place of *whomse* (or whom's) we have *whose*. (Also, sound aside, *whose* is no more related to *who's* than *his* is to *he's*.)

That's the quick-and-dirty, functional answer; it's also accurate that *whose* and *whom* evolved alongside each other, subject to different influences than what might make sense from our modern English point of view. From the OED Online:

> whose, *pron.* **Etymology**: Middle English *hwās*, later *hwǭs*, *whǭs*, altered form of
>   *hwas*, *hwes*, Old English *hwæs* (< **χwasa*) genitive of *hwá* and *hwæt*,
>   through the influence of *hwā*, *hwǭ* who pron., *hwām*, *hwǭm* whom pron.
>   (Later Middle English whas probably represents an unstressed variant.)

—"whose, pron." OED Online. Oxford University Press, June 2016. Web. 20 August 2016.

Comment: This is a great explanation in my opinion, thank you

Comment: It does raise other questions though... Where does the "e" in "whose" come from? If it actually means "who's", and and the word "his" doesn't have an "e", then it doen't really seem necessary.

Comment: Next question: Why is **Hims** not a word?

Comment: @MrLister: English spelling is weird?

Comment: Huh. After reading this, I think I may have been using "who's" when I should have been using 'whose'.

Comment: @Pureferret Isn't hims what you have when there are lots of him? ;)

Comment: @greenasjade excellent. Next,  exploring you->youm.

Comment: *Whose* isn't really *who's*, of course, anymore than *his* = *he's* (or *him's*). Basically, the language that became English had cases, and remnants of that system are now represented by various typographical conventions: the genetive ending -es became *'s* for most singular nouns (even those that originally might have had a different declension). But for some reason, pronoun cases didn't regularize and flatten out as much: compare I/me/my/mine/we/us/our/ours to something like apple/apple's/apples/apples'. (Though there is *one's*.) Organic languages are inconsistent like that. See...

Comment: The answer to this question for a more complete answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/origins-of-possessive-pronouns And also this WikiBooks article on Old English nouns: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/Nouns

Answer (score 52):

There aren't two different nominative/objective pairs

> *Who -> Whom*
>   *Whose* -> **Whomse*, **Whom's*, etc.

Instead, there's three choices

- *Who* -  Nominative
- *Whom* -  Objective
- *Whose* - Possessive

*Who* can't be both objective and possessive.

Comment: Times like these I wish I could accept two answers. Thanks for the explanation; it does feel if I say something like "For who(m)se dog did you buy the collar" is is both objective and possessive, but that's probably just an error in the way my brain "feels" about the sentence haha.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Examples of nominative and objective: ***I*** like ***her***. ***She*** ignores ***me***. ***Who*** likes ***whom***?   Examples of possessive: ***My*** dog ate ***my*** homework. ***Our*** team visited ***their*** stadium. Tomorrow, ***their*** team will visit ***our*** stadium.   See how the possessive is the same for the subject and the object.  (Indirect object and object of preposition are no different: ***He*** gave ***her*** a ring. ***His*** father proposed to ***his*** mother.)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: No, your brain is correct: in *for whose dog*, the noun group *whose dog* is together the object of the preposition; but internally, inside the noun group, *whose* is a possessive noun modifying *dog*. So there are both an object and a possessive/genitive there, though not at the same level. But the object is only indicated at the group level, and the group as a whole cannot show object status—except when the entire group is a single word *whom*.

Comment: +1. This, unlike the accepted answer, is an explanation.

Answer (score 17):

*Whose* is (originally and now) the genitive of *who*. From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=whose&searchmode=none):

> **whose**: genitive of *who*; from Old English *hwæs*, genitive of *hwa* (see *who*).

In all Indo-European languages that I know, a genitive modifies a noun but does not agree with this noun, not even in languages with elaborate paradigms. In other words, the form of the genitive doesn't change when the form of the noun it belongs to changes. An example from Latin:

> Magna Minerva est dea. "The great Minerva is a goddess."
>
> Amicus Vulcanus est deus. "Friend Vulcanus is a god."
>
> Vulcanus est amicus **Minervae**. "Vulcanus is Minerva's friend."
>
> Video amicum **Minervae**. "I see Minerva's friend."

As you see, the form of the genitive doesn't change, while the noun that the genitive modifies (*amicus/amicum*) changes form to indicate that it is subject or object, respectively. Only adjectives can change their form if they belong to a noun, not genitives. It is the same in English.

Comment: Your argument is invalid: cf `Est amicus meus` vs `Video amicum meum`.

Comment: Also, *whomse does exist in, say, Russian
"**Чья** это книга" vs "**Чью** книгу ты читаешь" (Whose book is this vs *Whomse book are you reading)

Comment: _meum, tuum, suum, nostrum, vostrum_ should perhaps be considered adjectives that have taken the place of genitive pronouns, rather than as pronouns themselves.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov: Possession can be indicated in other ways than through a genitive. As Anton says, *meus* etc. are adjectives, not genitives. The genitive of *tu* is rarely used, but it is *tui*, and it behaves like any other genitive. Your Russian example is very interesting! I don't know any Russian, but are those true genitives? Or could they be classified as something, such as possessive adjectives or suffixed words? Still, that doesn't mean they wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Sure, _meus_, [_чей_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9) and, say, [_यदीय_](http://sanskrit.inria.fr/cgi-bin/SKT/sktdeclin?lex=MW&q=yadiiya&g=Mas)  are all adjectives, not genitive pronoun forms.

But it is not immediately obvious that _whose_ is a descendant of a genitive form, and not an interrogative adjective like in Slavic or Sanskrit (a bunch of online grammars do classify _whose_ as an interrogative adjective).  This is where I see a minor logical gap (but it is filled by John's answer).

Comment: (Off topic: in Russian, even "Minerva's friend" is frequently expressed using a possessive adjective (Минервин друг). I can easily imagine an Indo-European language where genitives fell completely out of favor (like _tui_) and possession is exclusively indicated using adjectives.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov: Ah, I see. I assumed, but I suppose I should have added that to my answer. Done.