# "Each of whom's" or "each of whose"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case

I have been most certainly sure that the second is the better option until I came across the first expression from a [lecture](https://youtu.be/2zPEHYoiyfc?t=1h47m20s) by an American professor on EdX.

> And an array is a chunk of memory, each of whom’s elements are contiguous, back to back to back to back.

Can anyone elaborate which of the two is correct, and if both are, then which situations are they correct in?

Comment: Do you have a link to the lecture, or are you able to write down the sentence where "each of whom's" is used?

Comment: yes, given the link now

Comment: @sumelic He's provided the link now, from which I’ve transcribed the text. I fear this is yet another instance of “*whom*-hypercorrection”, the sort of thing that generates errors like *Give it to ⭑whomever wants it* for *Give it whoever wants it*, as well as *The prize goes to ⭑whomever’s horse places first* for *The prize goes to whosever horse places first*.

Comment: and *whomsoever* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate (with different improper spelling) of https://english.stackexchange.com/a/343884/15299.

Comment: @AlanMunn [This ngram disagrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+of+whose%2Ceach+of+who%27s%2Ceach+of+whom%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceach%20of%20whose%3B%2Cc0).